# Code doesn't work after importing another package

Tags: python, package, pycharm, python-import, manim

I'm currently working in PyCharm version 11.0.11 with Python 3.9, and I'm using Manim Community version 0.17.3.

In my project, the only library I had imported was Manim:

```
from manim import *
```

The code was working and then I added another library:

```
from manimlib.imports import *
```

It broke my code. After removing that line, my code still didn't work, and I received the error message:

```
   There are no scenes inside that module
```

It also isn't the code, when I create a new project and import (only) manim there everything works again.

My Questions:

- How is it even possible for a package to mess with my code, eventhough I don't have it imported? Did it overwrite something from the first package?
- How can I remove that one package that causes troubles from my Pycharm-project entirerly, I have tried to  "Optimize Imports" but that didn't help.

---

Since requested I'd like to show an example, this is my code that is working perfectly:

```
from manim import *

class test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        equation = MathTex(r"A=B")
        self.play(FadeIn(equation))
        self.wait(1)
```

I'm always calling it by typing this into my Pycharm-terminal:

```
 manim -p -ql main.py test
```

Now I'm changing nothing except adding the new line:

```
from manim import *
from manimlib.imports import *

class test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        equation = MathTex(r"A=B")
        self.play(FadeIn(equation))
        self.wait(1)
```

After installing the package to my pycharm-project, the code doesn't compile anymore and gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xxxx\pycharmprojects\manimbugtest\venv\lib\site-packages\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\xxxx\pycharmprojects\manimbugtest\venv\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "main.py", line 7, in construct
    self.play(FadeIn(equation))
  File "c:\users\xxxx\pycharmprojects\manimbugtest\venv\lib\site-packages\manimlib\animation\transform.py", line 27, in __init__
    super().__init__(mobject, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\xxxx\pycharmprojects\manimbugtest\venv\lib\site-packages\manimlib\animation\animation.py", line 31, in __init__
    assert(isinstance(mobject, Mobject))
AssertionError
```

After removeing that line from the code, one would expect that the code is working again, but by calling it I get:

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\manimbugtest> manim -p -ql main.py test
Media will be written to C:\Users\xxxx\PycharmProjects\manimbugtest\media\. You can change this behavior with the --media_dir flag.

   There are no scenes inside that module
```

Comment: including your code and how you're calling it would be helpful.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: The [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) says something related to the question: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."